# In pure javascript how do you transverse up a DOM element and target the parent?

Tags: javascript, dom

**Without using jQUERY** and just plain javascript. how would one select the parent of a child element?

example:

```
<div>
 <p>
  <em class="stuff">ABC</em>
 </p>
</div>
```

How would you select the parent div container via the class **stuff**?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.stuff').parentNode.parentNode`

Comment: I am downvoting this question because it displays a distinct lack of research effort. You would do well to include example code showing [what you've actually tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: many examples found while searching google are mainly jquery solutions. this wasn't easy to find which is why i posted it in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its in pure javascript

```
element.parentNode
```